# Link in Angular Openlayers Directive marker message not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, openlayers, apache-cordova

I made a simple mobile application using angular openlayers directive, i have my map and the markers i need, but in the html shown whithin the marker's message there is a link which takes you to another page, which is not working.

Is there a problem with the Angular Openlayers directive?, or am i doing something wrong?

It may have something to do with the fact that i'm making a ionic app in Apache Cordova for Visual Studio 2015?, i would show the code but it's almost exactly as the example i show here, the thing is, the links i put in the popup windows don't do anything on click.

Edit (again): Ok so now i have some example to show, i based it on this one http://embed.plnkr.co/oHzLdlUNiEnHZKYA6qdK/, and shows exactly the problem i'm having with the links inside the marker's windows, basically the link doesn't work, here it is: http://codepen.io/Orion390/pen/rrrQxm

```
$scope.markers.push({
  lat: Math.random() * 90 - 40,
  lon: Math.random() * 180 - 90,
  //message: $scope.markers.length +1
  message: "<a href='http://stackoverflow.com/' target='_self'> Lets post the question!! </a>"
});
```

Puts a marker with a link inside it's infowindow that does nothing on click

Update: This one actually works http://codepen.io/Orion390/pen/RGGZOE, i joust added a marker in the ng-init, like:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="addMarker()" >
```

Not really solving the problem, markers added after that still not working, but may have something to do with the marker windows being rendered behind a layer that does not let it get the click event?

Comment: can you post some code and show us what you have tried and struggled with  ?

Comment: Hello Nix, i am building the same maps as the examples in the question, except that they are inside an ionic app, and the info windows have links inside them, not joust an image or plain text, the issue is that they are not working when clicked

Comment: Also there is some code now :D

Comment: Btw, ended up only using data-tap-disabled='true' next to the openlayers directive, solved this and the contros problems, joust for everyone to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is your fix:

```
<ol-marker ng-repeat="marker in markers" ng-click="go()" ol-marker-properties="marker" >
  <a  data-tap-disabled='true' href='http://stackoverflow.com/' target='_self'> Lets post the question!! </a>
</ol-marker>
```

So you need to add `data-tap-disabled='true'` so your code.  But unfortunately this will get stripped out during bind-html.  So you are going to need to either disable the `sce` restrictions or use transclude and include the html you want inside of the `ol-marker`.  the other option is you put it up higher in the change on your `<openlayers>` maybe.

Ionic documentation on [tap](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/page/tap/)

Let me know if you need an updated codepen.

The code that broke it in ionic was:

```
  function tapClickGateKeeper(e) {
    //console.log('click ' + Date.now() + ' isIonicTap: ' + (e.isIonicTap ? true : false));
    if (e.target.type == 'submit' && e.detail === 0) {
      // do not prevent click if it came from an "Enter" or "Go" keypress submit
      return null;
    }

    // do not allow through any click events that were not created by ionic.tap
    if ((ionic.scroll.isScrolling && ionic.tap.containsOrIsTextInput(e.target)) ||
        (!e.isIonicTap && !ionic.tap.requiresNativeClick(e.target))) {
      //console.log('clickPrevent', e.target.tagName);
      e.stopPropagation();

      if (!ionic.tap.isLabelWithTextInput(e.target)) {
        // labels clicks from native should not preventDefault othersize keyboard will not show on input focus
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hello Nix,thanks for the info, the thing is, the app i am making will work on mobile devices, so i actually need to click the marker to open and view the window, an then to be able to click the link (or click outside to close it). I joust posted this as a bug on Github, if you want to check it https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/8138

Comment: Are you sure this issue is ionic ?

Comment: Yes, testing the same app using only angular without ionic works fine.

Comment: You are right I just found the block of code in ionic that does it.

Comment: See above @Orion390 you can use `data-tap-disabled`

Comment: You are the man!, i joust tested disabling the sce and works perfect, i will though explore the transclude option, it seems to be the better way, but for now disabling sce solved the problem, thank you very much!, (on how to disable sce https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

Comment: The integration between ionic and angular-openlayers-directive has been a hard one, extreme lack of documentation but i'm close to making it, only one thing left to have the openlayers map fully working, and it's the map controls, which do not work (as can be seen in the codepens i posted), i'll keep looking into that and maybe post antoher issue on the matter if i don't find a solution. Much Thanks again for the help!!